# Need Help in a lot of things

Tags: excel, cmd, treeview, smartsheet-api

In my company

I need to organized all files and folder from ALL servers into a Text, basally Inside the Platform Smartsheet.

I was writing all the names of the files and folder by hand, then, I realized that exist so many files, like crazy, will never end write them all!

So I tried to find an easy solution, and I find here a code in Windows that help a lot:

```
      Code:  Tree /f /a >file.txt   (I try to convert txt to CSV online, but if I changed the code to this in the end: >file.csv  also works xD don't need to convert)
```

Anyway, I need a solution to have in that code the SIZE of all files and folders, the boss wanna know the size of the all files too.

Then, other problem as, If I import to Smartsheet / Excel the tree effect (this is important the tree) don't works very well, and I'm crazy to figure out a way to do something like this: The tree effect while importing to smartsheet / excel need automatic have a hide / show lines (with symbol + and -). Like this photos:

with + : https://ibb.co/cLjQLpF

with - : https://ibb.co/g3Y2pps

To explain better: + means Folder and I want all folder (+) in a tree.
If exist a program that do this automatic much better, but I don't find no one.

Thanks
regards

Comment: see, if `(for /r "C:\" %a in (*) do @echo %%~fa,%%~za)>file.txt` fits your needs. See `for /?` for the `%%~...` modifiers (there are more of them)

Comment: didnt work, or maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: oh - a typo: on command line use a single `%`: `(for /r "C:\" %a in (*) do @echo %~fa,%~za)>file.txt`, in batch file double them `%%`: `(for /r "C:\" %%a in (*) do @echo %%~fa,%%~za)>file.txt`

Comment: thanks - but command said: %% was unexpected at this time.

Comment: on command line `%`, in batch files `%%`

Comment: thanks, but maybe Im doing something wrong: https://ibb.co/KxZyjcr

Comment: uhm - did you *translate* the commands??

Comment: Sorry, mistake...  but is the same: https://ibb.co/z54bNdt

Comment: ok, read my comments again and note that `%%:` is *not* part of the command.

Comment: so %% is for change for - or +? will try it

Comment: hmm, no... Maybe I need to said that Im not work in code, im  a noob in all this. I just try to find a solution in code to have a easy way to get Tree with all files and pholders to put in an excel. this code works: tree /f /a >list.txt - but dont give me the size of the all files. I saw in some websites to use code: dir /s /A:-D /d  - That works but not perfect. I wanna combine the 2 codes: tree /f /a >list.txt  with dir /s /A:-D /d  .

Comment: ok, if you never coded before, it might be a bit over your head. I'll try to be as easy as possible: open a `cmd` window and enter `for /r "D:\" %a in (*) do @echo %~fa,%~za`. This will output the full qualified filename (including Drive, path, filename inclusive extension), a comma, and the size of the file to the screen. If that looks helpful to you, we will continue from there.

Comment: Thanks - Now i figure out this code is more easy: dir /s /a /b >list.txt (Note: I use the command open here right click on the folder I wanna know the list) that code works, without tree, in fact the tree I do after inside the excel, because that code already divide the folder using this symble: \ - So while I import to excel i just have an option to put the symbol to divide the text into cells, then Inside the excel I do the hide and show raws by group then doing that I have + and - symbol) The only thing missing from this code: dir /s /a /b >list.txt   is the SIZE of all files :X

Comment: Using your code, have : "D:\"  I guess i dont need that because Im already using: right click cmd open here - I thing that is not necessary. And I need to end your code always with: >list.txt / >list.csv to get the text

Comment: change your code to this works and show the zise: for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~fa,%~za         But this show inside the CMD, while I cant export it. If I end that code using >list.txt  dont work, only show 1 file :X

Comment: you can see here: your code works this way: https://ibb.co/s96tr2j But list.txt only give me 1 file, not all :X But if i remove >list.txt I got all files but only iniside the cmd, like this:https://ibb.co/5s6nbrw

Comment: fine. You echo each line into the file (overwriting the previous content). Going back to my very first two comments, you'll notice, I enclosed the whole command in parentheses and so redirected the whole output in one go (instead of each line individually).

Comment: Sorry for hard understanding xD  but yes works using this: (for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~fa,%~za)>file.txt   My issue was I dont understand the symbol %% - using your code with 2 %% dont work, but if I use only 1 % works now :D  Thank you so much, Coding is hard so much OMG But I learned some good tips :D

Comment: Hey again, hope you dont mind to ask this: If I do that code works and its very helpfull, but I realized that they divide folder by \ in a line. When I put that in Excel I can get it all divided by \ but in horizontal way... And that is a little confused. So, maybe if I get inside the code a way for divide them not in horizontal but in vertical, could work even better. So, how I can do that? LIke this way: https://ibb.co/jhkq8Pn  I guess that is Tree afterall O.o